# Pipeline barriers between transfer write commands

Tags: vulkan

We have two transfer commands, `vkCmdFillBuffer()` followed by `vkCmdCopyQueryPoolResults()`. The transfer commands write to overlapping buffer ranges.

Is a pipeline barrier needed between the commands in order to avoid write-after-write hazards?

Does Vulkan provide any guarantee for commands executed in the same pipeline stage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you virtually always have to synchronize in Vulkan. There are only very few places where Vulkan does implicit synchronization.

You have the wrong intuition about pipeline stages. Commands indepentently "reach" stages of pipeline. All commands start at `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE` (they "reach" it in submission order). Then (without synch) it is not determined which command(s) will proceed to the next stage of pipeline. There's no order to it without explicit sync primitives. The spec would say something like "execution of queue operations **may** overlap or happen out of order".

So without sync `vkCmdCopyQueryPoolResults` may even happen before `vkCmdFillBuffer`, which I assume you do not want. If they both happen at the same time, that's even worse. The data may then contain some mess of writes from both sources (or from neither). The results would simply be undefined.

Comment: Data hazards in device memory should only result in undefined values, not undefined behavior. If there's something in the spec that suggests otherwise, I think it's probably a bug.

Comment: @JesseHall I think you might be right in the simple cases. But consider what happens if you wait on semaphore that was not signaled, or fail to flush non-coherent host memory, or do not make memory _available_ before layout transition, or use image in wrong layout. In either of those cases spec says you "must" do that right. Violating a "must" is by definition "undefined behavior". Anyway the point is the dev should never do it unless by accident. I will edit the answer as such.