# Vulkan: Is the rendering pipeline executed once per subpass?

Tags: vulkan

Considering a RenderPass that has multiple Subpasses:

Is the implication of multiple subpasses that the entire rendering pipeline is executed once per subpass?
And that the image output of a prior subpass is accessible to subsequent subpasses, assumming correct subpass dependencies?
(with the stipulation that reading prior image data happens at the same pixel location, for tile gpu optimation)
I understand that hardware may optimize things out; it's more of a way of thinking about how the multi-subpass processing happens.

Extending this to multiple renderpasses, then is it the same thing as subpasses? except that image data from prior renderpasses can be accessed at any location, and that the synchronization between renderpasses uses different mechanisms that between subpasses.

[image: Vulkan Rendering Pipeline]

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline is not "executed". Pipeline just exists. That's why it is called a pipeline, and not a state machine. The queue operations are the things that are executed.

With Vulkan's render pass it is good to know how tile-based architectures work. First they need to sort **everything** into tiles; that means they need to know the position of everything upfront. So, the geometry processing (vertex shader, geometry shader, tesselation shader, and all the relevant fixed-function stages) need to be finished for all the queue operations, before pixel processing (fragment shader, framebuffer writes, and other fixed-function stages) starts for any of them.

From that, the subpass restrictions are derived:

> If `srcSubpass` is equal to `dstSubpass` and not all of the stages in `srcStageMask` and `dstStageMask` are framebuffer-space stages, the *logically latest* pipeline stage in `srcStageMask` **must** be *logically earlier* than or equal to the logically earliest pipeline stage in `dstStageMask`

I.e. you cannot have a vertex shader dependency waiting on a fragment shader output of previous ops. But you can have "framebuffer-space" dependencies; e.g. fragment shader waiting on fragment shader of previous ops.

Comment: I feel that this is a good answer, but for a different question; one of dependencies. Ok, so pipelines are not "executed". But, isn't the idea that one can think of the gpu as performing operation described in the pipeline, in the order they are shown, and that there is programability in the steps, and hence the gpu acts as a... state machine? I understand that it can optimize steps and whatnot. But, I'm trying to have a mental model of how multi-subpass renderpasses are logically executed. i.e: they logically perform all the pipeline steps once per subpass, possibly in parallel.

Comment: @Dess: A pipeline is "executed" when you *render something* while that subpass is bound. Pipelines have to be created for a specific subpass, but that has no bearing on how often it gets used in that subpass (or when it gets used).

Comment: @NicolBolas: I guess I'm nickpicking now, but which do you mean?: that the pipeline is "executed" once per draw command, or once per subpass(ie: per vkCmd{Begin/End}RenderPass, per vkCmdNextSubpass)

Comment: @Dess: I don't know how I could possibly be more clear without repeating what I said. I don't know how you can get "once per subpass" when I said "has no bearing on how often it gets used in that subpass."

Comment: @NicolBolas: I understand that what you said is clear to you. But, other people have to interpret your words, and it's not always clear to them. For example, "render something": This could mean, invoke a draw cmd, or perhaps "render something" as the completion the totality of a subpass, once the data has been committed whatever render target.

Comment: @Dess: "*or perhaps "render something" as the completion the totality of a subpass*" Where does the Vulkan specification say that completing a subpass constitutes anything that could be called "rendering something"? My point is that your interpretation is being muddled by your misunderstanding of the use of the term "pass". You think that "pass" is about *rendering*, and it's not.

Comment: I've written a bunch of words and I still don't have a good mental model of evaluation sequence between/among subpass, as they relate to the rendering pipeline. What I do understand is good enough for rendering: sync stuff where required and rendering will happen.
I appreciate the discussion. Thanks.

Comment: @Dess Pipelining and a state machine are two completely different things. This is a very common misconception wrt Vulkan. It is perhaps confusing, because both can be represented with the same diagram with arrows. And yea, the difference is kinda important for your mental model. I go over the difference e.g. at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55088595/pipeline-barriers-between-transfer-write-commands/. With the better mental model, "pipeline being executed", is not a thing that has any meaning. The commands are executed. They all do so by walking through the pipeline stages, individually.

Comment: @Dess In your old mental model, you could say "the pipeline can be executed twice per subpass". I mean, if you add a dependency of `FRAGMENT_SHADER` of some commands to `FRAGMENT_SHADER` of other commands, it would have to right? Foremost though I would like you to get rid of this mental model, because it will bring you only misconceptions about things everywhere. Think of the pipeline as a desktop game playing board the commands walk on, **not** something that itself is executed.

Answer (score 1):

**Subpass dependencies** are just another abstraction of the Vulkan API of how to express the synchronization between different commands (each of which can run through multiple pipeline stages). W.r.t. render passes, subpass dependencies serve two purposes:

1. Expressing synchronization between *the commands submitted within* different render passes (that is when the `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` subpass-id is being used, see [`VkSubpassDependency`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkSubpassDependency.html)
2. Expressing synchronization between *the commands submitted within* the same or different subpasses. In this case, pairs of (`0` and `0`), or (`0` and `1`), and so on are specified for the `srcSubpass` and `dstSubpass` i a [`VkSubpassDependency`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkSubpassDependency.html) structure, respectively.

Given the correct synchronization scopes, a subsequent subpass can read the rendered results of a previous subpass. Framebuffer attachments can be passed on via *input attachments*, which are specified in [`VkSubpassDescription`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkSubpassDescription.html). You can get an overview of this in this [lecture](https://youtu.be/isbMMIwmZes) from [43:28](https://youtu.be/isbMMIwmZes?t=2608) onwards.

**Regarding the "rendering pipeline is executed"-thing:** The [lecture](https://youtu.be/isbMMIwmZes) mentioned above explains commands and how they
go through pipeline stages in quite some details starting from [22:29](https://youtu.be/isbMMIwmZes?t=1349). It should make things a lot clearer.

**Regarding tiled GPUs:** If you are referring to `VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT` for [`VkSubpassDependency::dependencyFlags`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkSubpassDependency.html), the spec says the following:

> VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT specifies that dependencies will be framebuffer-local.

That means, you can only use the following pipeline stages with that flag:

- `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT`
- `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT`
- `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT`
- `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`

Valuable information about tile-based architectures are given in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65049250/387023) by krOoze already.